# Can't import wxPython on OSX 10.11.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I cannot seem to get `wxpython` to install on Mac.  I have tried a number of approaches, but the closest I've gotten is using Homebrew.  When I do `brew list`, both `wxmac` and `wxpython` are listed, and when I type `brew link <n>` for either of those packages it says they're both already linked.  But when I go into python and try

```
import wxpython
```

I get:

> Error: no module named wxpython

So as far as I can tell, both packages are there, but my Python installation refuses to acknowledge them.

Answer (score 1):

Like some python libraries, the name of the library is different from the name that you should use to import it. For wxpython, you should use `import wx` instead of `import wxpython`

```
import wx
print wx.VERSION_STRING
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this and got `Error: no module named wx`.  So it seems like it's not just a naming problem.

Comment: @JeffD. Have you checked to make sure that you're running Homebrew's python and not the default OS X python? type `which python`

Comment: `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python`, but not sure how to find out where Homebrew is operating.  I have 2.6 (default) and 2.7 installed on my machine, but when I try to `import wx` using the IDE I have running in 2.7 it doesn't work either.

Comment: @JeffD. What does `which python2.7` give you? Typically homebrew would install to `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`

Comment: Hm, it gives `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`.  Is there any way to repoint Homebrew?  I really don't want to change where my Python 2.7 is located since I have several ongoing projects.

Edit: Or am I better off just using something else like Pip?  That's installed to `/Library/Python/2.7` right where it should be.

Comment: @JeffD. Do you have Macports installed as well? That's the version that it's trying to use. You can just point your IDE or your command line directly at `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`, alternately you can modify your `PATH` to point to `/usr/local/bin/` before `/opt/local/bin`